# IOS Objective C split a large UIView in to multiple UIViews and convert them into PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have this code that converts my `UIView` into `PDF`. 
Actually what I am doing is I have two string arrays, first array holds question strings and second array holds answer strings. I want to print the whole conversation and for that I am converting my `UIView` into `PDF`. But the issue is that I am dynamically increasing the size of `UIView` in accordance with the question answer strings. So, at the end of conversation view height becomes very large. Now I need to split that view into multiple views to print multi page `PDF`.

I already know how to print multiple page `PDF` from multiple `UIViews` but what I am struggling with is to how to split a large view in to multiple small A4 standard size views.

I am also saving the created `PDF` file into `document directory` but I don't need to know anything about that part that's why I am not showing that code inside this function.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename {  

NSMutableData* pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 612.0f, 792.0f), nil);
int  numberOfPages = ceil(aView.frame.size.height/792.0f);

for ( int i = 0 ; i < numberOfPages ; i++)
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
}
 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

 [self printItem:pdfData]; // I am using this function to print the pdf file

}
```

The code I am using here is printing multiple pages of same view repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) createPDF
{

    NSString *pdfFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",filePath];
    CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath]);
    NSUInteger totalPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);


    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

       for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
       {
           CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, i);

           CGRect cropBoxRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
           CGRect mediaBoxRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);
           CGRect effectiveRect = CGRectIntersection(cropBoxRect, mediaBoxRect);

           NSUInteger rotationAngle = 0;//;
           int pageAngle = (CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(pageRef) + rotationAngle) % 360;

           NSInteger pageWidth = 0;
           NSInteger pageHeight = 0;

           switch (pageAngle) // Page rotation angle (in degrees)
           {
               default: // Default case
               case 0: case 180: // 0 and 180 degrees
               {
                   pageWidth = effectiveRect.size.width;
                   pageHeight = effectiveRect.size.height;
                   break;
               }

               case 90: case 270: // 90 and 270 degrees
               {
                   pageWidth = effectiveRect.size.height;
                   pageHeight = effectiveRect.size.width;
                   break;
               }
           }

           if (pageWidth % 2) pageWidth--;
           if (pageHeight % 2) pageHeight--;

           CGRect pageFrame = CGRectZero;
           pageFrame.size = CGSizeMake(pageWidth, pageHeight);

           UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pageFrame, nil);
           CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
           CGContextSaveGState(context);


           CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
           CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, -pageFrame.size.height);
           CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, pageFrame, (int)rotationAngle, true));
           CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
           CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
           CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, pageRef);
           CGContextRestoreGState(context);
           CGContextTranslateCTM(context, pageWidth / 2, pageHeight / 2);
           CGContextRotateCTM(context, degreesToRadians(rotationAngle));
           CGFloat aspectRatio = (CGFloat)pageWidth / pageHeight;

           if (rotationAngle == 90 || rotationAngle == 270)
           {
               CGContextTranslateCTM(context, - pageHeight / 2, - pageWidth / 2);
               CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1 / aspectRatio, aspectRatio);
           }
           else
           {
               CGContextTranslateCTM(context, - pageWidth / 2, - pageHeight / 2);
           }

           UIImage *pageViewImage = [self getPageImageAtIndex:i];
           [pageViewImage drawInRect:pageFrame];

       }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
}


-(UIImage *) getPageImageAtIndex:(int) index
{

// Design page view and take snapshot of view with fixed number of questions and answers on view and return the snapshot image from here.

int startIndex = 0;
int endIndex = 0;

if(i==1)
{
   startIndex = 0; // start from 0 and draw upto 10
   endIndex = 10;
}
else if(i==2)
{
   startIndex = 11; // start from 11 and draw upto 20
   endIndex = 20;
}
else if(i==3)
{
   startIndex = 21; // start from 21 and draw upto 30
   endIndex = 30;
}
.
.
.
.

for(int i= startIndex; i<= endIndex;i++)
{

// Drawing goes here

}

}
```